# Layout adjustViewBounds is not wokring

Tags: android, layout, imageview, adjustviewbounds

I want the ImageView keep its aspect ratio with layout_height=match_parent
but I don't know why this happen ?

[image: bob]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/bob" />
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
          android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bob" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:background="@drawable/bob" />
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
          android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bob" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try removing adjustViewBounds

Comment: make height 

        android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: of your leniar layout

Comment: remove gravity from leniar layout

Comment: I dont know why this answer is up voted , this is NOT working at all

Answer (score 0):

Use for this to set in full image view scaletype=fitxy